# Can a .jme model be added to a GLCanvas(JOGL)?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, jmonkeyengine

I used jme to convert a Collada(.dae) model to .jme in order to to use it in an application.
I get the model loaded but now I would like to use it in a JOGL application using GLCanvas.
I have looked around to find out if it can be done to with no luck does anyone know if this can be done???

Answer (score 0):

JOGL is "just" a Java binding to the OpenGL API (with a few additional utilities and abstractions). If you would like to render a model with OpenGL (e.g. via JOGL) your application will have to load and render the model. There is no API for that. (jme is a engine on top of jogl/lwjgl - loading and rendering models is one of the features of every 3d engine).

Comment: So if I rendered the model using jme Can but jme ang JOGL be used in the same canvas? or container etc?

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to do low level OpenGL calls with jME.